# Solution to $n+\alpha W\left(-e^{\frac{-n}{\alpha}} \right) \leq 1$ for $n$, where $n\geq \alpha >0$, all in the reals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, lambert-w

Taking $\alpha$ as given, I am trying to know under which restrictions on $n$, the following holds:
$$ 0 \leq n+\alpha W\left(-e^{\frac{-n}{\alpha}} \right) \leq 1.$$
i.e I want to solve for $n$ the following two inequalities: a) $0 \leq n+\alpha W\left(-e^{\frac{-n}{\alpha}} \right)$, and b) $n+\alpha W\left(-e^{\frac{-n}{\alpha}} \right) \leq 1$.
In addition, I know $\alpha >0$, and that both $n$ and $\alpha$ are reals.

- The Lambert W function being defined only over the domain $[-1/e, + \infty)$, it must be in addition that $n \geq \alpha$.
  Which then ensures that a) holds.
- However I struggle to find any solution for the inequality b).

---

Hence, does anyone is able and kind enough to solve the following for $n$ ?
$$ n+\alpha W\left(-e^{\frac{-n}{\alpha}} \right) \leq 1 $$

With $n\geq \alpha >0$ and both $n$ and $\alpha$ in the Reals.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n) = n + \alpha W(-\mathrm{e}^{-n/\alpha}) - 1$.

We have, for all $n > \alpha$,
$$f'(n) = \frac{1}{1 +  W(-\mathrm{e}^{-n/\alpha})} > 0.$$

Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 &n + \alpha W(-\mathrm{e}^{-n/\alpha}) - 1 = 0\\
 \Longleftrightarrow & \,
 W(-\mathrm{e}^{-n/\alpha}) = \frac{1 - n}{\alpha}\\
 \Longleftrightarrow &\,
 -\mathrm{e}^{-n/\alpha} = \frac{1 - n}{\alpha}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1 - n}{\alpha}}\\
 \Longleftrightarrow &\,
 n = 1 + \alpha \mathrm{e}^{-1/\alpha}.
\end{align*}

Thus, the solution to $n + \alpha W(-\mathrm{e}^{-n/\alpha}) \le 1$ is $n \le 1 + \alpha \mathrm{e}^{-1/\alpha}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you mind detail a little bit what happens in-between the 1st and 2nd equivalence ? Namely, from W(...) = ... to -e^(-n/a)=...., it is not very clear to me. Thanks again tho!

Comment: @Banalaude You are welcome. Because the Lambert W function is the solution of the equation $W \mathrm{e}^W = x$, that is,  $y \mathrm{e}^y = x \Longleftrightarrow y = W(x)$.